# Google Action doesn't call again my oauth token endpoint

Tags: actions-on-google

I have activated account linking into Google Action to my IDP OAuth custom. We ran a test, Google tried to contact our token endpoint with refresh token (that we supposed Google had stored in previous correct call performed last week).
Since we deleted the refresh token in our repository, Google wasn't able to retrieve again a new access token and from the log, we have seen:

*"jsonPayload": {
"@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.identity.accountlinking.type.AccountLinkingError",
"response": {
"body": "{"error_description":"unable to retrieve account-device information","error":"E603"}",
"status": 400
},
"errorReason": "Could not refresh token, 3P returned error:E603",
"step": "REFRESH_ACCESS_TOKEN",
"request": {
"method": "POST",
"uri": "url_to_our_token_endpoint",
"body": "grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=REDACTED_VALUE",
"headers": {
"Authorization": "Basic Base64EncodedREDACTEDClientIdAndSecret"
}
}*

After this error, we tried again several times to run the same login test but Google never called our token endpoint. There were no logs in the console to understand why Google has not performed any other calls.
Does Google need to receive an error code different from our E603?
Why does Google not perform any other calls after the first error?